# Failed to create GLFW window

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

```cpp
#include "include/glad/glad.h"
#include "include/GLFW/glfw3.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "YoutubeOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 800);
    glClearColor(0.07f, 0.13f, 0.17f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I run it it shows failed to create GLFW window
can someone fix my code? or something

I was expecting for a window

Comment: Do you use a Mac? If yes: `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, true);`

Comment: Windows 10 why?

Comment: @JDUDEofficial: Did you install the graphics drivers downloadable from your GPU's vendor, or do you rely on Windows Update?

Comment: Done Downloading GLU Verndors

Comment: cough. Folks, if we advise JDUDE how to make things run on a single OS, on a single machine, using a specific driver, would we really help them? That seems like a terrible fate, needing to deal with every system's specificalities in your own code, especially if you're a beginner to all this.

Comment: it Appears my driver does not support OpenGL thanks btw

Comment: @JDUDEofficial that is almost certainly wrong.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is impossible to debug from this distance.

You will have to check the errors GLFW encounters.

You do that by registering an error handler call back function:

https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__error.html

In that function, you can log the error message to stdout or a file, for example.

Generally, reading your string "YoutubeOpenGL", I'd argue that directly working with GLFW might be a bit more low-level than you want. There's enough other frameworks that handle the system specifics for you, so that you don't have to do windows, linux, OS X… specific modifications yourself. The "big gun" in that is certainly Qt, which supports OpenGL accelerated graphics just as well, but also slimmer, and still quite low-level UI tool kits like DearImgui (with the glfw backend) would serve you better than trying to start with GLFW.